# Sending an email from a column on Google Sheets when I enter X in the last column

Tags: google-sheets, email

I am a high school teacher looking to streamline my late work process.  I have a google form the students fill out telling me their name, hour, email, and what assignment was late.  I added a column at the end for me to enter "x" in once I have graded their assignment and entered it into our gradebook.  I would like to be able to have the sheet auto-send an email to that student using the email they entered in Column C with a generic "your late work has been updated" message.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need a script that runs on an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), picks the email address from column `C` on the row given by `e.range.rowStart` in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), and uses [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) to send a message to that address.

See [sendEmailNotificationAndInsertTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/59313637?msgid=59488132) for sample code.